# What's the point of calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis()) right after instantiation?

Tags: java, android

In many posts and even on Google's site ([here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html#set)) I've seen this code :

```
// Set the alarm to start at approximately 2:00 p.m.
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

So I tested it in a standalone Java program (non Android) :

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(new Date(c.getTimeInMillis())));
```

Output :

```
01:23:33.884
01:23:33.876
```

It works fine without setting the time with setTimeInMillis explicitly.

What's the point of calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis()) ?
Is it erroneous, esp. in Android programming, to not set it this way ?

Comment: I would describe it more a "pointless" than "erroneous". I can't think of a good reason to re-initialize the time this way, other than to demonstrate "this is a way to set a time from a Unix epoch value" for illustration purposes.

Comment: Sample source code contains this reminder "Remember that clock-based time may not translate well to other locales, and that your app's behavior could be affected by the user changing the device's time setting." Could it be that calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis()) is invoked to override the (Android) device's locale specific parameters ? I'm still confused.